# Is a COLLATE statement needed after each column in a CREATE TABLE?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

If my table is in the `utf8_unicode_ci` collation, phpMyAdmin generates SQL code like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `other_varchar_column` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;
```

That seems like an awful lot of charset declarations. Can I can omit the ones at the end of each column, since the charset is also set at the end of the `CREATE TABLE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not required. Code generated by tools is often overly verbose.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: Thanks. I thought that would be the case.

Comment: I missed the one on the *CREATE TABLE*. Interesting to know did you run a SQL statement like 'SELECT id, name FROM table_name WHERE name = @some name'

Answer (score 0):

Answer I suppose yes for all character type data varchar , nvarchar etc.